# How many hours to remove and install a Cherokee 180 engine and prop

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, engine

How many hours should it take a shop to remove, install, and adjust the engine in a Cherokee 180 with a fixed pitch prop?

This would include the baffles and any hardware needed to be removed and installed for an engine swap.

Answer (score 4):

I once changed an engine in the bush when I was bush flying, helping the air service's mechanic.  It was a C-180 on floats (I had been forced down in it after the engine developed a loose cylinder from failed hold-down studs).

There was a rigid dock for us to work with at the remote lake we were at, and we used a bipod made of pine poles with a come-along to lift the engine and set it down on the dock (with the noses of the floats against the dock).

It took about 6-7 hours to have the engine and prop removed and ready to be loaded on the company Beaver when it showed up around 5 pm (loading it was the really entertaining part).

We went back in two weeks later with an overhauled engine and installed it, 2 mechanics and myself, and I flew it out that late afternoon around dinnertime.

So for a Cherokee sitting in a hangar with a lift handy, one mechanic with an assistant, about 4-6 hours to remove the engine, and about 6-8 hours to install it.  Certainly no more than two days at most.

Answer (score 2):

That's like a 2-4 day effort or more, depending on how many hands are helping, and what the condition of the removed items are. I saw a Cessna 172 get its engine replaced after an overhaul, these are all the things I remember being touched, and it was more than 4 days due to waiting for some parts to come in.

- cowling
- cowling mounts at front of engine
- spinner, prop
- baffles & springs, as you mentioned
- attachments & accessories, including:
- muffler & heat shroud
- starter & wiring
- magnetos (dual unit or 2 single units).  Does it/they need 500 hour IRAN?
- alternator, belt, wiring
- air hoses, maybe replace with orange SCAT hoses
- carburator
- throttle control
- mixture control
- carb heat control
- all the engine probes, incluuding:
- oil temperature
- oil pressure
- cylinder head temperature (may be 4)
- exhaust gas temperature (may be 4)
- fuel pressure
- maybe fuel flow
- maybe carb throat temperature
- replace the engine mounts if they are old/stiff
- fuel connection
- oil filler/dipstick tube
- oil filter (any adapters for spin-on filters)
- oil filter screen
- crankcase breather tube
- vacuum pump
- connections to oil cooler (and flush it out)

A lot of things are safetywired too, so that has to be all addressed as they go back on. Then securing all the wiring & hoses & tubing. My AP/IA won't let things be tiewrapped to the engine mount, ADEL clamps protect the engine mount and provide attachment points.

And I'm probably missing some things too. Then there's documenting it all.

Comment: Thanks so much for your details-Al